# Django - Data in form is clearing out when sent to database

Tags: django, forms, one-to-one

I have created a view that should update some data about a user in the database. Earlier I had issues with populating the page, but with 'user7485741' I played around with the data until I was able to populate the form how I wanted to. However, when I hit submit the database is wiped clean of data. I mean if I have a price of '$2.00' that I set in the database and then in the html page I change it to '$3.00', the database shows $0.00 in the backend. Indeed, I see that `print(self.cleaned_data)` returns `{'user': <User: a.a@a.com>}`. It isn't capturing any other fields.

Thanks!

Models.py

```
 class Person(models.Model):
        user            = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
        price           = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
        travel_flag     = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default = False)
```

forms.py

```
class Meta:
    model = Person
    fields = ['user', 'travel_flag','price']
```

views.py

```
class UserProfileUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    form_class = UserProfileChangeForm
    template_name = 'accounts/profile-update-view.html'

    def get_object(self):
        qs = Person.objects.filter(pk=self.request.user.person.user_id).first()        
        return qs

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(UserProfileUpdateView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['title'] = 'Update Your Profile'
        return context

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("account:home")
```

html page

```
<form method='POST' action='{% if action_url %}{{ action_url }}{% endif %}'> {% csrf_token %}
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="id_price" class="active">Price: $</label>
    <input id="id_price" type="number" name="currency" min="0" max="99999" step="0.01" size=4 value="{{ user.person.price }}">          
</div>      
<div class="form-check">
    <input id="id_travel" type="checkbox" name="travel" value="yes" {% if user.person.travel_flag %}checked{% endif %}>
    <label for="id_travel" class="active"></label> 
</div>      
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Have you tried searching the docs? [Form handling with class-based views.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/)

Comment: In `get_object` of your view, try returning `self.request.user.person`, because you want to edit the Person instance, not the User instance.

Comment: Thanks @user7485741, I ended up going with a query set, but your suggestion led me to a lot of thinking. I've broken down my process a lot and figured out that the error was in my html page.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Turns out if your cleaned_form isn't passing back data, it could be because the form is not setting that field. In my case above I have

```
<input id="id_price" type="number" name="currency" min="0" max="99999" step="0.01" size=4 value="{{ user.person.price }}">
```

when I should have

```
<input id="id_price" type="number" name="price" min="0" max="99999" step="0.01" size=4 value="{{ user.person.price }}">          
</div>
```

The name on an html page corresponds to the field in the database that you are updating.